# Slow transfer to USB on Ubuntu 20.04 but fast on Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, usb

I recently switched to Ubuntu 20.04 after getting pissed of by Window's lack of wanting to work, apart from some small issues on linux almost everything seems to just be working for me but when transfering any files to a USB drive it quickly jumps to saying 100% done and then takes forever to actually transfer properly and say done.

I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 but on Windows 10 a transfer that takes me 10 mins on linux only takes around 10 seconds.

any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: How big is the transfer and how much memory do you have?  What filesystem on the USB?  USB2 or USB3?  Does the whole system slow down, and do you have any free memory when the copy slows?  Search this site for "slow copy" and see some suggestions that might help.

Comment: transfer size doesn't matter, whether small or large it's super slow on Linux and fast on windows, 16gb RAM, FAT32 but I've tried NTFS and it wasn't any faster on Linux, USB2, whole system doesn't slow and I have memory free during the transfer.

I have an HDD if that is relevant.